# Sagemaker Studio Notebook - How to access OS Environ

Tags: python, bash, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to set (at the terminal or in the notebook) an environment variable. I am running the following in the terminal or (with %%bash in the cell) notebook cell:

```
echo "export MY_KEY='BLAH-BLAH123'" >> ~/.zshrc
source  ~/.zshrc
```

or

```
echo "export MY_KEY='BLAH-BLAH123'" >> ~/.bash_profile
source  ~/.bash_profile
```

But when i run:

```
import os
os.environ["MY_KEY"]
```

The key is not found. What am i doing wrong? It must be something with an image versus the terminal??

Answer (score 0):

This should work. My guess is that the rc files you are sourcing exit too early, before executing the command you added at the very end of them.

You can verify that by doing:

```bash
declare -p MY_KEY
```

... just after sourcing your files (this command works both in zsh and bash).

If you get an error message, telling you the variable is not defined, then take a look at your rc files and see what is wrong.

Alternatively, you can also do `set -vx` before sourcing your files, and `set +vx` after that. You will then get a full list of the commands that were actually executed and you may understand better why your last command was not.

That said, defining an environment variable can be done in command line, either with:

```bash
$ export MY_KEY='BLAH-BLAH123'
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["MY_KEY"])'
```

or just with:

```bash
$ MY_KEY='BLAH-BLAH123' python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["MY_KEY"])'
```